# Is -o-border-image property necessary?

Tags: html, css, image, border, border-image

I want to use an image as a border and found the following code:

```
-moz-border-image: url(".....
-webkit-border-image: url(".....
border-image: url(".....
```

what had missing is the opera property like transition has: `-o-transition`

Would it be wise to add it as

`-o-border-image`

or is it not necessary ?

Comment: no it's not, even the -moz- and -webkit- are useless, you can remove them

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand `border-image` is somehow buggy on most older browsers.
Better use the seperate properties:

```
border-image-source
border-image-slice
border-image-width
border-image-outset
border-image-repeat
```

The `border-image-repeat` property was buggy for a long time.

```
Opera: fixed in version 43
Firefox: fixed in version 50
Chrome: fixed in version 56
Safari: fixed in version 9.1
Edge: no problem
```

So I think it's better to use the seperate `border-image-___` properties and avoid using `border-image-repeat` to support older browsers. In this way you don not have to use the -moz-, -webkit-, or -o- prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixed properties should almost never be used in production since they are used for unstable and experimental features so the behaviour may be inconsistent or cause other problems.

Support for `border-image` (**without** a vendor prefix) has been in:

- IE since version 11
- Edge since version 12 (current version 80)
- Firefox since version 15 (current version 74)
- Chrome since version 15 (current version 80)
- Safari since version 6 (current version 13)
- Opera since version 15 (current version 66)

[source](https://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image)